# dataframe count unique list values from a column and add the sum as a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

```
data = {
    's1': [[1, 2], [None], [2, 3]],
    's2': [[4, 5], [6, 7], [3, 2]]
}

output:

        s1     s2
0   [1, 2]  [4, 5]
1      NaN  [6, 7]
2   [2, 3]  [3, 2]
```

I need to get a unique counts of each elements for these columns `s1` and `s2` and also add these counts as a row like:
EDIT: also need to ignore None/null values from the count.

```
expected output:
  step      count
0    1      4 -> since [1,2,3,NaN] <<- EDIT this should only be 3 ignoring NaN
1    2     6  -> since[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

What I did was a bit dirty:

```
s1_unique = df['s1'].explode().unique()
s2_unique = df['s2'].explode().unique()
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['step] = [1,2]
new_df['count'] = [len(s1_unique), len(s2_unique)]
new_df['name'] = 'Others'
```

Is there a "neat" dataframe way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with a set count apply over each column + flattening with numpy concatenation:

```py
data = {
    's1': [[1, 2], [None], [2, 3]],
    's2': [[4, 5], [6, 7], [3, 2]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.DataFrame( {'step': range(1, 1+df.shape[1]),
               'count': df.apply(lambda x : len(set( np.concatenate(x.values))), axis=0)}
            )

#   step    count
# s1    1   4
# s2    2   6
```

Edit:

Not counting `None` values:

```py
pd.DataFrame( {'step': range(1, 1+df.shape[1]),
               'count': df.apply(lambda x : len(set( np.concatenate(x.values)).difference({None})), axis=0)}
            )
```

or

```py
pd.DataFrame( {'step': range(1, 1+df.shape[1]),
               'count': df.apply(lambda x : len(set( value for value in np.concatenate(x.values) if value is not None)), axis=0)}
            )
```

Comment: is there a way to ignore `null` in this case?

Comment: Check my updated answer for that

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
out = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"step": step, "count": len(df[c].explode().unique())}
        for step, c in enumerate(df, 1)
    ]
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   step  count
0     1      4
1     2      6
```

---

Or:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"step": c, "count": len(df[c].explode().unique())}
        for c in df
    ]
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  step  count
0   s1      4
1   s2      6
```

Answer (score 1):

So in your case

```
out = df.sum().map(set).map(len)
Out[97]: 
s1    4
s2    6
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you would like to ignore None:

```
df.sum().map(lambda x: len({i for i in x if i is not None}))
```

or

```
df.stack().explode().groupby(level=1).nunique()
```

Output:

```
s1    3
s2    6
```